# Event handler in a loop seems to invalidate every code written below it

Tags: mysql, loops, event-handling, datagrip

I was working on my database project, and I tried to make a stored procedure that will generate a data into a column automatically whenever this procedure is called (it is called automatically into a procedure that I use to insert data into a table).

I'm using Cursor to iterate through my table, and since i'm not used to Cursors yet, I took [a page out of this example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/). However, when I tried to run the code in DataGrip, it showed that every code in the loop, below the event handler are marked as Unreachable Code. My guess is that either DataGrip or the loop itself treats the Event Handler as a break statement, and this seems to be true, since when I moved my event handler, the previously Unreachable code stops getting tagged as Unreachable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generateTF()
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_transac_ID INT; DECLARE v_dpptotal INT; DECLARE v_tprice INT; DECLARE v_tdisc INT;

DECLARE generate_tf CURSOR FOR
    SELECT transaction_id, dpptotal, total_discount FROM transaction;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
   FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

OPEN generate_tf;

generate : LOOP
  FETCH generate_tf INTO v_transac_ID, v_dpptotal, v_tdisc;
  if v_finished = 1 THEN
  LEAVE generate;
  END IF;
  --From here
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT total_price FROM transaction WHERE transaction_id = v_transac_ID) THEN
  UPDATE transaction SET total_price = (SELECT totalprice(v_dpptotal)) WHERE transaction_id = v_transac_ID;
  END IF;
  SET v_tprice = totalprice(v_dpptotal);
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT final_price FROM transaction WHERE transaction_id = v_transac_ID) THEN
  UPDATE transaction SET final_price = (SELECT finalprice(v_tprice, v_tdisc)) WHERE transaction_id = v_transac_ID;
  END IF; --To here, is unreachable.
END LOOP generate;

CLOSE generate_tf;

END;
```

I tried putting the handler at the bottom of the loop, but as expected, it doesn't do anything, even though it does relieve the code from being unreachable, but it only makes the loop iterate once, I think.

I expect this to be a problem with the way I used the event handler or the loop. I did try to search if anyone is having the same problem, but found nothing.

Comment: The continuation handler is in the right place and your code does syntax if submitted to mysql directly.Can you add your create statement and clarify how your declared variables are set.

Comment: Added CREATE statement just now. The declared variables don't have set values initially, the Cursor directly fetches values into them, and one of them (v_tprice) is set by assigning a value from a function-call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue, which is fixed and is going to be released. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7554

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.